# Combining elements of list of lists by index

Tags: r, list

Consider the following list of lists:

```
lst = list(list(c(1,2), c(3,4)),list(c(5,6), c(7,8)),list(c(9,10), c(11,12)))
```

The list `lst` contains three lists, each list containing two vectors as elements. I would like to combine the elements of the underlying lists by index. In other words, I would like to merge vector 1 from list 1 with that of list 2 and list 3, and vector 2 from list 1 with that of list 2 and list 3, etc...

This is the result I am looking to achieve:

```
res = list(c(1,2,5,6,9,10), c(3,4,7,8,11,12))
```

I know that this can be achieved as follows in case of two separate lists:

```
mapply(c, lst1, lst2)
```

However, I am not sure how to replicate the same logic using a list of lists.

Any efficient way to achieve that? Please keep in mind that in reality, `lst` is a list of 5000 lists, and each underlying list contains a large number of vectors.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe  `sapply(1:length(lst) function(j)list[[j]][[1]])`  and similarly but ending in `[[2]]` will suffice?

Comment: The problem is that in reality, each of the individual lists contain wayyy more vectors, and not only 2. It wouldn't be efficient/feasible to write the same equation indefinitely for each vector.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do:

```
do.call(Map, c(c, lst))
```

Comment: Nice. I guess ours are basically identical, but `Map` sure is cleaner.

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting the following error when applying it to my practical problem: `Error in match.fun(f) : '100' is not a function, character or symbol` ...

Comment: maybe you have a variable `c` thar has a value of `100`. You could replace `c` above by `base::c`.

Comment: Great thanks. Would this work if the underlying lists have elements as matrices, and not vectors?

Comment: depends what you want to do with matrices, you might want to replace `c` by `cbind` or `rbind`.

Comment: I have never worked with Map before. Could you please show me how you would adapt it to achieve that? I have tried changing to `cbind` but it is not doing the trick..

Comment: @Mariam - in that case you may be better off learning what `cbind` and `c` and `mapply` actually do.  It sounds like you're a bit new to the paradigms under which `R` works.

Comment: `Map` is like `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`. I was suggesting you try `do.call(Map, c(cbind, lst))` but it's hard to tell exactly without an example.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I actually am very familiar with those methods, and I have modified the above formula using cbind and couldn't achieve the proper result

Answer (score 7):

You're on the right track:

```
do.call(function(...) mapply(c,...,SIMPLIFY = FALSE),args = lst)
[[1]]
[1]  1  2  5  6  9 10

[[2]]
[1]  3  4  7  8 11 12
```

Comment: Great thanks! How about if each underlying list contains matrices and not vector, and I would want to merge the matrices next to each others. How can I adapt your formula to doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something along the lines of the OP's question... but with a list of data frames instead of vectors. In that case, slightly modifying @joran's answer above gives the desired result. Consider:

```
mylist <- 
  lapply(1:2, function(y){
    df1 <- data.frame(a=y, b=y^2, c=y^3)
    df2 <- data.frame(d=y, e=y+1)
    return(list(df1=df1, df2=df2))
    })
```

You can then re-combine the sub-list elements into separate data frames based on their common indexes:

```
mylist2 <- do.call(function(...) Map("rbind", ...), mylist)
```